# jquery tabs not transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I decided to try my hand in jQuery `$('#tabs').tabs();` and make my tabs vertical. I ran into the problem of not having the content show upon selection of a tab. An example of the problem is [here - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/275/) I know there's clearly something I'm missing. I tried looking at the Jquery UI documentation, but was still unaware of what I was doing wrong. I would be grateful to know why I'm having this problem and any other tips would also be greatly appreciative

Comment: You also have duplicate `id`s.  This is invalid html, you can't have more than one element with a particular id.

Comment: Ok thanks for that piece of advice @jmoerdyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

You need some extra CSS (your JS Fiddle isn't loading the jQuery UI CSS) for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Requires extra fiddling, but here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWqXS/)

Comment: Ok, the updated fiddle is horizontal. The goal is vertical, I'm taking a look at the link you sent me now

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- You have duplicate element `id`s.  And the first instance of each `id` points to the link, not the content.  Remove the `id`s from the links.
- The tabs widget is dependent on CSS.  Add the [base stylesheet](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) in and it works.

[jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/280](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/280/)

To get the layout you want, you'll have to start with the [base stylesheet](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and modify it.

Comment: @Octavius - To get the layout you want, you'll have to start with the [base stylesheet](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `ID` cannot appear on one page twice.  Remove it from your `<li>` tags.  Secondly, for some reason jsfiddle isnt pulling the relative css data.  I cut and pasted mine into there and it works now.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/279/

Answer (score 0):

I included some code in the head section.Here it is.

```
      <head>        
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Vertical Tabs functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
      <script>
       $(function() {
         $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
         $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
       });
      </script>
      </head>
```

Reference:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Working Model:
http://jsfiddle.net/abhijalgaonkar/qTXnN/

Try not to modify the css in the source css file.Over riding the css would be a better option.

Let me know if it helps....